# Inserting data in a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have two classes with ManyToMany relationship.

**Student.java**

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "student_class", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")},
                                        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "class_id")})
    private List<Class> classList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Class.java**

```
@Entity
public class Class {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "classList",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Student> students;
}
```

My question is how to implement a POST request in the controller? Do I add class to classList for a student and the student will automatically get inserted into students list?

Comment: Get the entities, add them to each other and save them using the repository.

Comment: Thanks, will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that will actually be monitored by JPA for references is the one pointed with `mappedBy` .

This means that JPA  during a save or update or delete will consider the mappings that the `Student` holds on `classList`. Therefore the cascade you have written here has no point.

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "classList",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Student> students;
```

The only cascade that will actualy work is the one pointed with `mappedBy`

```
 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "student_class", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")},
                                        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "class_id")})
    private List<Class> classList = new ArrayList<>();
```

So to your question

> Do I add class to classList for a student and the student will
> automatically get inserted into students list?

Yes it will be added to the list so you can see it, but it will not consider any changes that you make to that studentList. So if you make modifications directly on studentList then those modifications will not be persisted in your database.